# How to properly track only one specific subdirectory in directory in Git?

Tags: git, wildcard, gitignore

I understand you can use the NOT to allow an exception. But based on [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore),

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

Is there any way around this? For my case specifically, I have a folder called `model_results`, with many subfolders. I want to ignore every single subfolder in `model_results`, EXCEPT subfolders that are appended with `_final`, one specific subfolder in those, called `model`

This is what I've tried to no avail:

```
# ignore subdirectories within model_results
model_results/**
# un-ignore these
!model_results/*_final/model
```

This still ignored `regtree_final/model`

If it is possible, I suspect the reason for mine failing is the way I'm using wildcards.

Comment: why would the documentation state that it is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directroy of that file is excluded, if it were somehow possible? you'll need a solutino that does not exclude the parent directory

Comment: Search for "gitignore unignore" and you get plenty of work-arounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Recursion: see recursion

It's important to understand, here, that Git uses a *recursive search* to find files.  What does this mean?  Well, the joke version is the section title here, but in fact, we start with an initial directory (or folder, if you prefer that term) to search:

```
func search(prefix string, d Directory) {
    for element in (all files and subdirectories in d) {
        skip = false
        name = element.name
        full_name = prefix + name
        type = element.type  # file, directory, or "other"
        switch type {
        case type_file:
            if not_in_index(full_name) and is_ignored(name, full_name, type_file)
                 skip = true
        case type_directory:
             if is_ignored(name, full_name, type_directory)
                 skip = true
        case type_other:
             skip = true
        }
        if skip {
            // don't even look at this any more
            continue
        }
        if type == type_file {
            git_add(full_name)
        } else {
            subdir = opendir(full_name)
            search(full_name + "/", subdir)
            closedir(subdir)
        }
    }
}
```

—except that the actual code is tremendously more complicated for various reasons.  **But the key is this: if we hit an ignored *directory*, we never *look inside* that directory!**  So if we ignore `model_results/regtree_final` (the directory), we never see any of the *files inside* `model_results/regtree_final` and therefore never add any of them.  We never test to see whether they're ignored, or un-ignored, or whatever.  We just never bother with the entire directory.

To make sure that we *do* look inside `model_results/regtree_final`, we must arrange for `is_ignored(name, full_name, type_directory)` to say "no, this is not ignored".  So how do we do that?

Well, we can explicitly *un-ignore* the name `regtree_final`, or the full name `model_results/regtree_final`.  That would require a line of the form:

```
!regtree_final
```

or:

```
!model_results/regtree_final
```

as a *separate line* in the `.gitignore` file that occurs *after* the `model_results/**` line.

#### Side notes

Side note: if we do ignore, say, `model_results/blah` we don't need to carefully also ignore `model_results/blah/zonk` because we'll never *look at* `model_results/blah` in the first place and hence never *test* `model_results/blah/zonk`.  So as written, the `**` is overkill.  It's not *wrong*, it's just unnecessarily inclusive.  Whether it will become right or necessary later is another question that you'll have to ask yourself later.

Secondary side note: I prefer to use the simple names in a `.gitignore`, rather than names containing embedded or leading slashes.  That is, instead of a top level `.gitignore`, I'd rather have a file named `model_results/.gitignore` in which I list the things to ignore that live within `model_results`.  This is a personal preference item and you may or may not be using some third-party software that prohibits this anyway, so it's up to you whether to adopt a similar preference.  Just remember that there's an important difference between anchored and un-anchored entries in `.gitignore` files and when you use a top-level `.gitignore` to ignore entries in lower-level directories, *all* your entries for that lower level directory are by definition anchored: you have no choice here.  When using a `.gitignore` at the same level as the files, you have a choice.  You might still want anchored entries, e.g., `/*` and `!/*_final/`, but you have the *option* of going either way, whereas with the top-level final, your entries are all anchored.

#### Un-ignoring some or all sub-directories

Now, I mentioned that to explicitly un-ignore `regtree_final` you could use:

```
!model_results/regtree_final
```

Note that you can also write:

```
!model_results/regtree_final/
```

The *trailing slash* here means "apply this rule if and only if this name is a directory name".  That's why the `is_ignored` calls in the sample pseudo-code pass the entry's type.  Rules like this, that *end with slash*, mean "match only if the type is directory".

The problem with un-ignoring `regtree_final` like this is that it's necessary but *not sufficient*, as you want *all* `*_final` directories un-ignored.  You can achieve this with:

```
!model_results/*_final/
```

Here we've used the trailing slash to mean *directories only, no files please* and the leading `!` to means *un-ignore*, i.e., *do* look inside this directory.

Now, if `model_results/regtree_final/` contains *another directory*, e.g., if you have:

```
model_results/regtree_final/one/file1.ext
model_results/regtree_final/two/file2.ext
```

there's a problem with your `model_results/**` line above, because *that line ignores `model_results/regtree_final/one`.

If you have no sub-sub-directories, this isn't really a problem, but when you do get into deeply nested, "bushy" directory structures, it gets a little tricky.

One handy trick for Git ignore files is `!*/`.  This is an *un-anchored* expression, so it applies to all names found anywhere.  But it's a trailing-slash expression, so it applies only to *directory* names ... and it's an "un-ignore" rule because it starts with `!`.  So it *completely defeats* the directory optimization that Git uses.

That is, when we hit the:

```
    case type_directory:
         if is_ignored(name, full_name, type_directory)
```

section of the code, we're always going to say "no, don't skip".  Git will always look inside every directory, and slowly and painfully test *every* file in *every* directory.  **This is slow!**  It's a Big Hammer.  Use with caution.